# Compile Lua Code and store the bytecode in a new file

Tags: c#, lua, luac

I know it is possible to compile the `Lua` code using [LuaC](http://www.lua.org/manual/4.0/luac.html) as described here:

> luac is the Lua compiler. It translates programs written in the Lua programming language into binary files that can be loaded and executed with lua_dofile in C or with dofile in Lua.

The problem is: I need to create an application in `.Net` (more specifically in `C#`) that will receive an input of multiple 'regular' *.lua files and then compile all of them to new files.

Comment: That's a link to **very** old lua documentation for the record. Are you asking how to do what luac does in your own code? Have you tried looking at the luac source?

Comment: I'm wondering if is there a library that could do that for me...

Comment: Yes, lua. Look at the code for luac.

Answer (score 2):

`loadfile` followed by `string.dump` does essentially what `luac` does.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to call LuaC.exe from inside my application.

My solution was doing the following:

```
string outFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(path) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + ".out";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\luac.exe", "-o \"" + outFile + "\" \"" + path + "\"");

path = outFile;
```